Excel Pivot Table On Separate Row
Is there anyway I can make the Contract Value Covered it's own separate row instead of being a column?
enter image description here

Please post your data as text, not image.

click in the pivot table then the PivotTable Fields box should open up (if not to click on ribbon PivotTable Analyze> Show> Field List). Drag whatever is in the column box to the rows box. Maybe drag the rows to the column box...

I meant when I add it to the new row combines my data don't want it to combine
